# Angular: RequestAnimationFrame and ChangeDetectorRef for updating view

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

In Angular, after a view has initialized, one part of it might be recalculated dynamically; in particular:

- When `someStream$` updates
- I read the value of an already rendered element in the DOM
- And set the value of another element (its height) according to the read value
- an attribute listener in the template sets the height accordingly to the `viewHeight`value

So the code looks like this:

```
this._subs.push(this.someStream$.subscribe(() => {
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      const spaceTop: number = this.hostEl.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      this.viewHeight = window.innerHeight - spaceTop;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  });
}));

<someElement [style.height.px]="viewHeight"></someElement>
```

I need ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); to apply the changes instantly. My question is, why do I also need requestAnimationFrame? Why does the code not work without it? From my understanding requestAnimatoinFrame triggers re-rendering (in a browser-optimized way), but NgZone, activated by ChangeDetectorRef, should do that already.